# Windows Impersonation and TPL

Tags: c#, winforms, task-parallel-library, impersonation

I am using `WindowsIdentity.Impersonate` in order to read from remote registry. However, the actual code that is reading registry located in `Task` delegates, so it may run on different threads. My question is whether it is legit to impersonate in UI thread and do the elevated job in Thread Pool?

UPDATE:

```
// get userHandle from LogonUser(...)    
Task task = Task.Run(() => 
{
    using (impersonationContext = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(userHandle))
    {
        // Do stuff here
        if (impersonationContext != null)
        {
            impersonationContext.Undo();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *legitimate*?

Comment: I mean even if it works on my first attempt, in some cases it will not fail. Trying to understand if impersonation is applied on current thread or on all threads/process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use TPL, which are available from .NET Framework 4.0. `WindowsIdentity` should flow automatically, unless you explicitly suppress flow.

> In the .NET Framework versions 1.0 and 1.1, the `WindowsIdentity` does not flow across any user-defined asynchronous points. In the .NET Framework version 2.0, there is an `ExecutionContext` object that contains information about the currently executing thread, and flows it across asynchronous points within an application domain. The `WindowsIdentity` also flows as part of the information that flows across the asynchronous points, which means that if an impersonation context exits it will flow as well. [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229296.aspx)